# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while

Tags: swift

I face a problem with my app. I'm using `func importPhoneBookContact`, and get:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

when I run the app at:

```
cnContacts.remove(at: cnContacts.index(of: contact)!)
```

How do I send a nil string to my function?

```
func importPhoneBookContact(){
    let keysToFetch = [
        CNContactGivenNameKey, // Formatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
        CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
        CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
    var cnContacts = [CNContact]()
    var phoneNumbers = [String]()
    let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()
    let store = CNContactStore()
    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: request){ (contact, cursor) -> Void in
            cnContacts.append(contact)
        }

        if cnContacts.count > 0 {
            for contact in cnContacts {
                if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
                    for phone in contact.phoneNumbers{
                        if PFUser.current() == nil {
                            return
                        }

                        var phoneNumber = phone.value.stringValue
                        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()

                        if (phoneNumber.count) > 3 {
                            if String(phoneNumber[..<phoneNumber.index(phoneNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)]) == "00" {
                                phoneNumber = "+"+String(phoneNumber[phoneNumber.index(phoneNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)...])
                            } else if String(phoneNumber[..<phoneNumber.index(phoneNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)]) != "+" {
                                if let code = (PFUser.current() as! User).countryCode {
                                    phoneNumber = "+"+String(describing: phoneNumberKit.countryCode(for: code)!)+phoneNumber
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if phoneNumbers.contains(phoneNumber){
                            cnContacts.remove(at: cnContacts.index(of: contact)!)
                        } else{
                            phoneNumbers.append(phoneNumber)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            AppDelegate.contacts = cnContacts
            print("phone book contacts: ", AppDelegate.contacts.count)
        }
    } catch let error {
        NSLog("Fetch contact error: \(error)")
        AppDelegate.contactsImported = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!`. Don't assume `index(of:)` will succeed.

Comment: Also, as a general rule it's a bad idea to mutate an array while you're looping through it.

Comment: Curious - why do you enumerator all of the contacts building your own array, then start to iterate that list of contacts, check for phone numbers, iterate each of the contact's phone numbers, and then, after all of that, finally check if `PFUser.current() == nil`? Why not make that check the first thing you do in this import function?

Comment: Side note: Never ever check for an empty array with `.count > 0`, there is an `isEmpty` property. And both checks are redundant anyway. If an array is empty the `for` loop will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Montgomery have already pointed never mutate array in looping. 
So instead of doing removing object while looping I'll suggest to maintain array of object that you want to remove and at the end remove them.
below is my updated version.

```
func importPhoneBookContact(){
    let keysToFetch = [
        CNContactGivenNameKey, // Formatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
        CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
        CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
    var cnContacts = [CNContact]()
    var phoneNumbers = [String]()
    let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()
    let store = CNContactStore()
    var contactsToRemove = [CNContact]()
    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: request){ (contact, cursor) -> Void in
            cnContacts.append(contact)
        }

        for contact in cnContacts {
            if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
                for phone in contact.phoneNumbers{
                    if PFUser.current() == nil {
                        return
                    }

                    var phoneNumber = phone.value.stringValue
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()

                    if phoneNumber.count > 3 {
                        if phoneNumber.prefix(2) == "00" {
                            phoneNumber = "+"+String(phoneNumber[phoneNumber.index(phoneNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)...])
                        } else if phoneNumber.prefix(1) != "+",
                            let user = PFUser.current(),
                            let code = user.countryCode,
                            let countryCode = phoneNumberKit.countryCode(for: code) {
                            phoneNumber = "+"+countryCode+phoneNumber
                        }
                    }

                    if phoneNumbers.contains(phoneNumber) {
                        contactsToRemove.append(contact)
                    } else {
                        phoneNumbers.append(phoneNumber)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cnContacts = cnContacts.filter({ contactsToRemove.contains($0) })
        AppDelegate.contacts = cnContacts
        print("phone book contacts: ", AppDelegate.contacts.count)
    } catch let error {
        NSLog("Fetch contact error: \(error)")
        AppDelegate.contactsImported = true
    }
}
```

Comment: And yes this will take care of that crash too :)